# How to design activities like the uber app

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment

I am building an app like uber, I have problems with some concepts I don't know.

1. How to make the animation when a view is swiped from bottom to top, it will merge with the toolbar until then the view is in a activity.
2. How to maintain or load the same map in all activities of the app.

Note: I don't know if the Uber app uses activities, fragments or otherwise.

[Image: Picture before you start sliding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhVgC.png)

[Image: Activity merged with the toolbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYZxK.png)

Answer (score 1):

For swipe a view from bottom to top, you can use bottom sheet android component which presents a dismissible view from the bottom of the screen and for animation you can define translation or transition animation for the component. [Here](https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet) is one github repository.

With regards,

Answer (score 0):

Better yet, try using bottomSheetDialogFragment. though what i cant say is if it will give you a fullscreen merge with the other activity but it has features like drag already implemented. [Here is a link to a tutorial you can follow](https://www.google.com.ng/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwix07KS-4rUAhXEXBoKHSk3A84QFggmMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmedium.com%2Fglucosio-project%2Fmoving-from-dialogs-to-bottomsheetdialogs-on-android-15fb8d140295&usg=AFQjCNHlo6MV0LaxWiXO2FWdSK8pNtkQFg&sig2=cgDUEGf3di9_bBzdh9wFEg)